# R neuralnet package

Tags: r, neural-network

I have a huge dataframe that has 76801 columns. Column names are v1, v2...v76801
My Y variable is v76801 and all remaining variables are x variables. I am struggling to write my neuralnet equation. I tried below method but it failed.

My dataframe name is m

method1

```
net.sqrt <- neuralnet(v76801~.,data=m, hidden=5, threshold=0.01)
```

error

```
> net.sqrt <- neuralnet(V76801~.,data=m, hidden=5, threshold=0.01)
Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

method2

```
xnam <- paste("V", 1:76800, sep="")
fmla <- as.formula(paste("V76801 ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+")))
```

error

```
> fmla <- as.formula(paste("V76801 ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+")))
Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
```

Comment: Have you tried to set --max-ppsize=500000 when you start R?

Comment: No, how do i do that? i tried max-ppsize=500000 but got an error : Error in max - ppsize = 5e+05 : could not find function "-<-"

Comment: You could start R from the command prompt.   Navigate to the directory containing the R.exe (e.g. on my Windows machine, I enter `cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64`).  Then, I start r with the --max-ppsize parameter (e.g. enter `R --max-ppsize=500000`).